# Finding the highest average salary of a department using joins in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the below schema:

```
Table 1
-------
empID
empName


Table 2
-------
empID 
department  
salary
```

Assuming the tables are:
Table1:

```
empID|empName
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    E
6    F
7    G
8    H
9    I
10   J
```

Table 2:

```
empID|department|salary
1    X    10
2    X    10
3    X    10
4    Y    5
5    Y    5
6    Y    5
7    Y    5
8    Y    5
9    Z    3
10   Z    3
```

I need to find the department name with the highest average salary and display them along with the employee names.

The output I am expecting is:

```
empName|department|salary
A         10        
B    X    10
C         10
```

This was an interview question, and I am recreating this from memory so it might not be perfect. I am also picking up SQL after a gap of more than 2 years. Please suggest if I am missing something.

The query that I have formed is:

```
SELECT
    table1.empName,
    TOP(1) AVG(table2.salary),
    table2.department
FROM
    table1
INNER JOIN
    table2
    ON table1.empID = table2.empID
GROUP BY
    table2.department
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza did you have trouble understanding my question?

Comment: @TarunGupta - Juan is giving you resources because your question is low quality right now. If you want help, you need to make your question clear and understandable.

Comment: @Nicarus I get that. I am new and my question quality will improve with time. Although if I was in your place, as long as I can understand what someone is asking I would try to help them. If I don't understand something I would ask for clarifications. Maybe my question is not framed as per your standards. But is my question incomprehensible?

Comment: @TarunGupta - You should not feel defensive, we are just trying to help you better frame your question so you can get good answers. You question is not, at least to me, incomprehensible; however, unless you provide details and examples it is possible those answering with (a) misunderstand all or part of the question or (b) not want to put the energy into answering your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: none right now, this question was asked to me at an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks like SQL Server (the "TOP 1").  In that database, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t1.empName, t2.salary, t2.department
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.empID = t2.empID
ORDER BY AVG(t2.salary) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.department) DESC;
```

A more generic solution:

```
SELECT empName, salary, department
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY avg_salary) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT t1.empName, t2.salary, t2.department,
                   AVG(t2.salary) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.department) as avg_salary
            FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
                 table2 t2
                 ON t1.empID = t2.empID
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I draw from your question, I would approach it this way.

```
WITH department_rank AS
(
SELECT
    department,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY avg_salary DESC) AS avg_salary_rank
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        department,
        AVG(salary) AS avg_salary
    FROM
        table2
    GROUP BY
        department
    ) tbl
)

SELECT
    dept.department,
    emp.empID,
    emp.empName,
    dept.salary
FROM
    table2 dept
JOIN
    table1 emp
    ON  (emp.empID = dept.empID)
JOIN
    department_rank drnk
    ON  (drnk.department = dept.department)
    AND (drnk.avg_salary_rank = 1) --Top ranked department based on average salary
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. making functions in SQL is totally new to me. I understand the logic behind your code. I have edited my OP and added some more details. I thought this question could be done with just one query. Please check the edited post.

Comment: I'm not following what you are asking. I've added a screenshot of the output - it gives you the result you are seeking. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes the output you got is what I want.